# Perspective based reading - Artifact created

Tags: testing, code-reviews, review

From what I have learned, in Perspective based reading, the document/code/etc., is inspected from different perspectives. We consider roles like software designer, tester or user.

Each role follows the scenario assigned to them, and reads the code/document, etc. Each role also creates an artifact; for example the person in role of tester creates a test plan, etc

My question is with regards to that artifact. What exactly is it based on? Is it based on portion of the code/document that scenario specifies? So they have the original document, and they create a new partial document??

Also, can a person in role of tester create an artifact of user manual or design? or based on his role, he has to create only the artifact related to his role? Many thanks for any help.